# DNS Lookup over SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, vpn, dns, tunnel, lookup

On Linux or Mac OS X how can I perform DNS lookups over an established SSH Tunnel?

How can I restrict DNS lookups of the form *.mydomain.com

Can I redirect all attempts to access domains of the form *.mydomain.com via the SSH tunnel?

I basically want to be able to SSH, RDP, and browse the web as if I was connected to the internal network. Standard VPN software I have is kind of buggy with my OS and with an SSH tunnel I have more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just concerned about DNS while browsing, Firefox has a configuration setting for this:

```
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns
```

If you set the value to true, DNS calls will use your SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a long piece about doing this end to end from within a corporate network. The article contains masses of extra stuff which it sounds like you may not need, but I also touch on the DNS specific stuff.

Take a look here : http://godeater.cream.org/vpn.html